# Get PHP data on TPL file

Tags: php, smarty, whmcs, whmcs-invoice-template

I am new to WHMCS and php and i would like to add a new custom php file that displays all the tlds and their pricing ...

For that, i have created a new file : domainList.php under  /public_html/ directory :

domainList.php

```
<?PHP

use WHMCS\Authentication\CurrentUser;
use WHMCS\ClientArea;
use WHMCS\Database\Capsule;

define('CLIENTAREA', true);

require __DIR__ . '/init.php';

$ca = new ClientArea();

$ca->setPageTitle('Your Page Title Goes Here');

$ca->initPage();


$ca->setTemplate('domainList');


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/includes/api.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    http_build_query(
        array(
            'action' => 'GetTLDPricing',
            // See https://developers.whmcs.com/api/authentication
            'username' => 'GGT3m7EqO7bxnrb1HcT9i1z0tKOcmA03',
            'password' => 'qRFYmqc7JDNprtGxFFwKBJzHyaGxMSbv',
            'currencyid' => '1',
            'responsetype' => 'json',
        )
    )
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$jsonData = json_decode($response, true);


$ca->output();
$smarty->assign("response", $response); 

?>

in the domainList.tpl file i have the following code :
```

in the domainList.tpl file i have the following code :

```
{foreach $response['pricing'] as $tld => $price}{$tld} : {$price['register']['1']}{/foreach}
```

```
But i could not get the variable $response populated directly in the tpl file from the php file


i would like to send an array from php to tpl file and loop through it and display it in the tpl file
```

reponse contains the following data :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDogp.png)

Comment: I hope its not a real username / password

Comment: Are you sure you want to inject `$smarty->assign("response", $response);`  instead of `$smarty->assign("response", $jsonData);`?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to dump $response, it could be empty or not well formed.
As @MarkusZeller said it's more logical assigning `$jsonData` to `response`.
Note that `json_decode()` returns *null* if provided data can't be decoded.